# Constructing a parametric data type

Tags: haskell

I am trying to define a data type in Haskell. This datatype will be called 
Node. It will be able to contain a parametric type a  or Nothing. I defined it so:

```
data Node a = Node (Maybe a) deriving (Show)
```

When I load it in GHC the following works 
Node Nothing

However when I type this for example 
Node (6)

I get the following error:

```
Non type-variable argument in the constraint: Num (Maybe a)
    (Use FlexibleContexts to permit this)
    When checking that ‘it’ has the inferred type
      it :: forall a. Num (Maybe a) => Node a
```

Why is that?  what am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The statement `data Node a = Node (Maybe a) deriving (Show)` creates a data constructor (which is a function) of type `Node :: Maybe a -> Node a` in other words, you need to pass a value of type `Maybe a` to this function.

You have passed `6` which is not of type `Maybe a`.

Instead you can pass a `Just 6` value like so:
`Node (Just 6)`.

Comment: Thanks a lot. This explanation makes it a lot more clearer to me. Cheers.

Answer (score 4):

You have defined your datatype using `Maybe`, so you have to wrap the value in `Just`:

```
Node (Just 6).
```

If you just want to have a type which can be either empty or have defined value, define it in the following way:

```
data Node b = Empty | Node b deriving (Show)
```

Comment: Thank you very much. It works excellent with Just. If I would like to construct a Node which takes something or may be empty without using the Just word, is there any way to do it?

Comment: Thanks a lot. With this example along with the explanation from Chris I think I got it. Cheers.